# $p$-adic rings are definable in $p$-adic fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, first-order-logic, p-adic-number-theory

I want to show

> $p$-adic (normed, local, henselian ring) rings is definable in $p$-adic field by a first order formula.

If $p\neq 2$ we have
$$\forall x\in \mathbb{Q}_{p}, \,\,\, x \in \mathbb{Z}_{p} \leftrightarrow \exists y \,\,\, y^{2}=1+px^{2}.$$
To prove this we use the henselian property of $p$-adic rings and this fact
$$\mathbb{Z}_{p}=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}_{p}\,\, \vert \,\, |x|\leq 1\}.$$
More precisely,

If $x\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ then $\overline{f}(1)=0$ and $\overline{f}(1)\neq 0$ by henselian exists $y$ is true in equality. If $x$ be true in equality then $|x|\leq 1$ by use valuation map
$$v(x)=n \leftrightarrow p^{n}\mid x,\,\, p^{n+1}\nmid x$$
and $|x|=2^{-v(x)}$.

But if $p=2$ we have
$$\forall x\in \mathbb{Q}_{2}, \,\,\, x \in \mathbb{Z}_{2} \leftrightarrow \exists y \,\,\, y^{2}=1+8x^{2}$$
I can't prove this because if $x\in\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ then $\overline{f}(1)=0$ and $\overline{f}(1)=0$ in $\mathbb F_{2}$.

Please help me.

Comment: If $a\in 1+p\Bbb{Z}_p$ then for all $n\ge 0$ there is $y\in \Bbb{Q}_p$ such that $y^{p^n-1}=a$.

Comment: I'm guessing some of the $f$ should be $f'$?

Comment: If $x \not\in \mathbf Z_2$ then $x = u/2^n$ for $|u|_2= 1$ and $n \geq 1$. Check separately for $n = 1$ and $n \geq 2$ that $1 + 8x^2$ is not a perfect square (odd $2$-adic valuation when $n \geq 2$). If $x \in \mathbf Z_2$, use a *more general* version of Hensel's lemma, not just the one that works for simple roots mod $p$.